# Last character when parsing from sys.stdin not printing properly

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and for some reason I have a strange problem with negative indexes. Instead of getting the last character I get an empty string. And instead of getting all character but last I get the whole string back. Here is the code I'm using:

```
print('Starting loop')
for line in sys.stdin:
   last = line[-1]
   print 'last = ' + last 
   allButLast = line[:-1]
   print 'AllButLast = ' + allButLast
```

The result:

```
Starting loop
123
123
last =  

AllButLast = 123
last = 

AllButLast = 123
```

Comment: The last character is a line break `\n`.

Comment: @Rawing Why don't you add this comment as an answer?

Comment: @Bonifacio2 Probably was unconfident to post as an answer worrying people would downvote for being too short of an answer

Comment: @Bonifacio2 It's because I'm having trouble convincing myself that this is a useful question that should be kept around. I have a hard time with questions that can be answered in less than 10 words...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `line = line.rstrip()` at the beginning of the `for` loop to get desired value. Currently newline is being captured as `line[-1]`, so you need to remove that first. The *enter* that you press just after typing `123` is nothing but a *newline*.